# Regex to capture text after a specific char

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to capture all text after the final / in an expression e.g. for myname/is/john, I want to capture "john" but the regex I have written `/[^/]*$` returns "/john". How can I get it to return just john and not /john?

Comment: which flavor of regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can rely on the input to contain at least one `/`, then you can just match text that does not include it:

```
[^/]*$
```

You will get the maximal match.

Answer (score 5):

```
/([^/]*)$
```

You can use this and capture the `group`.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'myname/is/john';
r = /\/([^\/]*)$/;

result = r.exec(s)[1];

console.log(result);
```